# Capturing (perturbatively) non-equilibrium field theory effects using "elementary" methods

Tags: quantum-field-theory, research-level, perturbation-theory, non-equilibrium, thermal-field-theory

I am considering a system of two interacting scalar fields: $\psi$, and $\phi$. The Lagrangian is given by:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}[\psi]=\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\psi\partial^\mu\psi+\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\chi\partial^\mu\chi-\frac{{m_\psi}^2}{2}\psi^2-\frac{{m_\chi}^2}{2}\chi^2-\frac{\sigma^2}{4}\chi^2\psi^2
\end{equation}

$\psi$  is initially in a near vacuum state, while $\chi$ is initially supposed to be in a thermal state. For simplifying the calculations, the thermal state is taken as a state of definite occupation numbers, following the Bose-Einstein distribution. The interaction between $\chi$ and $\psi$ can be assumed to be small, and we can treat $\chi$ as an unchanging background for $\psi$. The exact definition of "small" is not given here, as it will be clear later that it is also part of my question.

I want to calculate, perturbatively, the excitation of $\psi$ as function of time due to its interaction with the thermal bath $\chi$. Since I need to know the dynamics of $\psi$ at an arbitrary time, the final state cannot be assumed to be an equilibrium or free state, so the Gell-Mann-Low theorem does not apply. The problem is I know neither a general method to calculate the effect of $\chi$ on $\psi$, nor an approximating method that still captures that effect. I am satisfied to know the least general method that gives a non-zero excitation, preferably using canonical approach. (I have a limited knowledge of QFT of non-equilibrium systems and finite temperature field theory, so I want to avoid them if possible.)

It would be most ideal for me to know what excitation effects we can capture considering different simplifying assumptions (for example, based on different levels of smallness of the coupling between the fields), and (for each simplifying case) the specific methods we can use to account for these effects. I know a complete answer is very unlikely, so a partial one would be very much appreciated still.

One canonical approach I tried is given below. Is there a different approach, more sophisticated perhaps, but still written in canonical/elementary language, that at least gives a non-zero $\psi$ particle production effect?
I understand that canonical approach must eventually fail. But for my purposes, accuracy is not very important. I am ready to decrease the complexity/generality of the problem, by adding more and more assumptions, perhaps until the canonical approach is adequate. Of course the more generality is preserved, the happier I am. So another way to put it is: What is the most complicated case that we can treat using canonical language?

(One approach that may produce result and can be treated using canonical language is of quasiparticle, but I don't know how to implement it. At some point the concept of particle is no longer valid, but if the coupling is weak enough, then $\chi$'s effect on $\psi$ might be sufficiently described by thinking of $\psi$ as a collection of dressed particles - quasiparticles.)

---

[The failed try] We derive the Euler-Lagrange equation out of the lagrangian above,
\begin{equation}
(\square+\lambda^2|\phi_0|^2)\psi=-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\chi^2\psi
\end{equation}
Then, take the Fourier transform
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2\psi_k(t)}{dt^2}+\omega^2(t)\psi_k(t)=J_k(t)
\end{equation}
Where $\psi_k(t)$ and $J_k(t)$ are the Fourier transforms of $\psi(x)$ and $-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\chi^2\psi$ respectively.
and then I define the following "Hamiltonian"
\begin{equation}
\text{"}H_{\textbf{k}}\text{"}=\frac{1}{2}p_{\textbf{k}}^2+\frac{1}{2}\omega_{\textbf{k}}^2\psi_{\textbf{k}}^2-J_{\textbf{k}}(t)q_{\textbf{k}}
\end{equation}
with $q_{\textbf{k}}=\psi_{\textbf{k}}$, and $p_{\textbf{k}}=\dot{\psi}_{\textbf{k}}$. We assume that we can still define the annihilation operator as
\begin{equation}
a_{\textbf{k}}(t)=\sqrt{\frac{\omega_{\textbf{k}}}{2}}\left[q_{\textbf{k}}(t)+\frac{i}{\omega_{\textbf{k}}}p_{\textbf{k}}(t)\right]
\end{equation}
The evolution of this operator is given by the following Heisenberg equation
\begin{equation}
\frac{da_{\textbf{k}}}{dt}+i\omega_{\textbf{k}}a_{\textbf{k}}=\frac{i}{\sqrt{2\omega_{\textbf{k}}}}J_{\textbf{k}}(t)
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
a_{\textbf{k}} (t)= a_{\textbf{k}}^0 e^{-i\omega_kt}+ \frac{i}{\sqrt{2 \omega_k}} \int^{t}_{0} dt' e^{i \omega_{\textbf{k}}(t'-t)}  J_{\textbf{k}}(t')=a_{\textbf{k}}^0 e^{-i\omega_kt}+A_{\textbf{k}}(t)
\end{equation}
where $a_k^0$ is the evolving unperturbed annihilation operator, and we denoted the second term as $A_{\textbf{k}}(t)$.

The plan is take the expectation value of the time varying occupation number operator $N_k=a_k^\dagger a_k$. Since I do not know how to construct a state in the interacting theory, the best I can try is to sandwich the occupation number operator by a state $|s\big>$ obtained by taking the direct product of a free state of $\psi$ with definite occupation numbers and a free thermal state of $\chi$:
\begin{align}
\big<s|a_{\textbf{k}}^{\dagger}(t)a_{\textbf{k}}(t)|s\big>&\approx\big<s|(a_{\textbf{k}}^{0})^{\dagger}a_{\textbf{k}}^0|s\big>+\big<s|(a_{\textbf{k}}^0)^{\dagger}A_{\mathbf{k}}e^{i\omega_kt}+A^{\dagger}_{\textbf{k}}a_{\textbf{k}}^{0}e^{-i\omega_kt}|s\big>\\
&=\alpha_{\textbf{k}}+2\text{Re}\left[\big<s|(a_{\textbf{k}}^0)^{\dagger}A_{\mathbf{k}}e^{i\omega_kt}|s\big>\right]\\
&=\alpha_{\textbf{k}}+2\text{Re}\left[\frac{i}{\sqrt{2 \omega_k}} \int^{t}_{0} dt' e^{i \omega_{\textbf{k}}t'}  .\frac{-\sigma^2}{2}\int d^3p\int d^3q\big<s|(a_{\textbf{k}}^0)^{\dagger}\chi_{\textbf{q}}\chi_{\textbf{p}-\mathbf{q}}\psi_{\textbf{k}-\textbf{p}}|s\big> \right]
\end{align}

Using $\psi_{\textbf{k}}(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[a_{\textbf{k}}v_{\textbf{k}}^*(t)+a^\dagger_{-\textbf{k}}v_{\textbf{k}}(t)\right]$ and $\chi_{\textbf{k}}(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[b_{\textbf{k}}V_{\textbf{k}}^*(t)+b^\dagger_{-\textbf{k}}V_{\textbf{k}}(t)\right]$, we have

\begin{align}
\big<s|(a_{\textbf{k}}^0)^{\dagger}\chi_{\textbf{q}}\chi_{\textbf{p}-\mathbf{q}}\psi_{\textbf{k}-\textbf{p}}|s\big>e^{i\omega_kt}&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}\big<s|(a_{\textbf{k}}^0)^{\dagger}\left[a_{\textbf{k}-\textbf{p}}^0v_{\textbf{k}-\textbf{p}}^*+(a_{\textbf{p}-\textbf{k}}^0)^{\dagger}v_{\textbf{k}-\textbf{p}}\right]\left[b_{\textbf{q}}V_{\textbf{q}}^*+b_{-\textbf{q}}^{\dagger}V_{\textbf{q}}\right]\left[b_{\textbf{p}-\textbf{q}}V_{\textbf{p}-\textbf{q}}^*+b_{\textbf{q}-\textbf{p}}^{\dagger}V_{\textbf{p}-\textbf{q}}\right]|s\big>\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}\big<s|\left[(a_{\textbf{k}}^0)^{\dagger}a_{\textbf{k}-\textbf{p}}^0v_{\textbf{k}-\textbf{p}}^*\right]\left[b_{\textbf{q}}b_{\textbf{q}-\textbf{p}}^{\dagger}V_{\textbf{p}-\textbf{q}}V_{\textbf{q}}^*+b_{-\textbf{q}}^{\dagger}b_{\textbf{p}-\textbf{q}}V_{\textbf{p}-\textbf{q}}^*V_{\textbf{q}}\right]|s\big>\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}\left[\alpha_{k}v_k^*\delta^{(3)}(\textbf{p})\right]\left[(\beta_q+1)V_q^*V_q\delta^{(3)}(\textbf{p})+\beta_qV_qV_q^*\delta^{(3)}(\textbf{p})\right]
\end{align}
where $\alpha_{\textbf{k}}$ and $\beta_{\textbf{k}}$ are, respectively, the $\psi$ particle number and $\chi$ particle number number of $\textbf{k}$ mode. Therefore,
\begin{align}
\big<s|(a_{\textbf{k}}^0)^{\dagger}A_{\mathbf{k}}|s\big> e^{i \omega_{\textbf{k}} t}&=-\frac{i\sigma^2}{8\sqrt{\omega_k}} \int^{t}_{0} dt' e^{i \omega_{\textbf{k}}t'}\left[\frac{\alpha_k}{\sqrt{\omega_k}}e^{-i\omega_kt'}\right]  \int d^3q \left[(2\beta_q+1)\frac{1}{\omega_q^{\chi}}\right]\\
&=imaginary
\end{align}
where we used $v_{\textbf{k}}=\frac{e^{i \omega_{\textbf{k}} t'}}{\sqrt{\omega_{\textbf{k}}}}$. Therefore $\big<N_{\textbf{k}}(t)\big>\approx\alpha_{\textbf{k}}$

We see that this approach produces a trivial result: no $\chi$ particle is produced. This is to be expected, since the $\psi_k$ operators only act on the $\psi$ part of the Hilbert space, and the $\chi_k$ operators only act on the $\chi$ parts. So, there is no mixing among the modes of $\psi$ and $\chi$.

Comment: This is an open-systems problem that could be treated using various standard techniques. The issue is more complicated than canonical examples because 1) the problem is relativistic and 2) the "open system" here (the field $\psi$) is itself a many-body system. One approach could be to assume that $\chi$ is a delta-correlated (perfectly Markovian) environment, and try to either derive a master equation or an effective action by tracing over/integrating out $\chi$. The first approach is treated in Breuer & Petruccione, the second in U. Weiss' book.

Comment: In general I think you will need to give $\chi$ some dynamics otherwise there will be no fluctuations to perturb $\psi$ and lead to particle creation/thermalisation.

Comment: @MarkMitchison Thanks for your comments.
I understand that canonical approach must eventually fail. But for my purposes, accuracy is not very important. I am ready to decrease the complexity/generality of the problem, by adding more and more assumptions, until the canonical approach is adequate. Of course the more generality is preserved, the happier I am. What is the most complicated case that we can treat using canonical approach?

Comment: Your fluctuation point seems promising and is new to me. What is the most natural form of fluctuation $\chi$ can have? And how can it produce non-zero effect when non-interacting states is used to sandwich the occupation number operator?

Comment: The simplest thing would be to just give $\chi$ a kinetic term $(\partial\chi)^2$ in the Lagrangian. You want to keep the Lagrangian for $\chi$ quadratic. Then integrating out $\chi$ should give you an additional interaction term for $\psi$, so that the non-interacting $\psi$ vacuum is no longer an eigenstate. I don't really understand what you mean by the "canonical" approach in your comment. I am not talking about "canonical quantisation", I am using the word canonical as in "usual", "well-studied" etc. As I said there are many canonical approaches in this sense.

Comment: @MarkMitchison Yes, what I mean by "canonical" is as you understand - "usual", "well-studied". Actually, my failed try already took into account a kinetic term and a bare mass term of $\chi$. It's just I forgot to specify it; I've edited the Lagrangian in the question.

Comment: @MarkMitchison So, even after taking into account the dynamics of $\chi$, I still got not excitation. Is integrating out a kind of approximation? If yes, then I could not see how it could capture interaction while my exact method fails. Or is it a (generalizing) step toward the interacting theory? I do not have established knowledge on integrating out for now. Could you please explain to me, or give some reference (and examples) on how to perform this procedure?

Comment: By integrating out he meant the bath degrees of freedom. You do this to get an effective description of the system alone. You can then under other approximations on the bath dynamics reduce the entire unitary time evolution to an effective master equation, e.g., Redfield or Lindblad. 

However, as I see your Lagrangian as written it is not technically a non-equilibrium problem. It is just two coupled scalar fields. Why not use standard perturbation theory? Am I missing something?

Comment: Also googling for: lagrangian with "two interacting scalar fields" gives lots of relevant hits, e.g., (page 45) of
https://books.google.com/books?id=SdP9alEcltQC&pg=PA45&lpg=PA45&dq=lagrangian+with+"two+interacting+scalar+fields"&source=bl&ots=YI85jQCddZ&sig=mtU2W7CjX23T1n0wAMPMUeLXv5E&hl=en&sa=X&ei=G4l0VbWCCurW7Qa9zIDYCA&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=lagrangian with "two interacting scalar fields"&f=false , 


Physica A189, 651 (1992)

Comment: @Bubble As I understand, the perturbative prodecures in standard intro to qft textbooks only apply if we are interested in the fate of a system long after it is perturbed, i.e. the initial and final states are both free states. Here, op is interested in calculating the transient time evolution of a system(the $\psi$ field), where the perturbation(due to $\chi$) is never turned off. So in this sense the problem is a non-equilibrium one, am   I right?

Comment: @zudumathics How necessary is it that the interaction term be $\chi^2\psi^2$? I think you will find it much easier to consider $\chi\psi^2$, since then the equation of motion for $\chi$ can be exactly solved and substituted into the equation of motion for $\psi$.

Comment: @MarkMitchison : Yes, it is necessary for my purpose.
Emitabsorb: Yes, what I meant by "non-equilibrium" is also as you understand. Btw thank you for putting a bounty.
Bubble: Thank you for your suggestion. I will read them before coming back on this point.

Comment: I think the second term in the lagrangian should be a kinetic term for the second field, not an interaction term?

Comment: @MarkMitchison I just edited the post to present the failed approach more detailed. The dynamics of $\chi$ is stored in the time-dependent mode functions $V_{\textbf{k}}(t)$. As you can see, this dynamics does not contribute to the $\psi$ particle production if we sandwich the particle numbers operator with the state of definite occupation number of $\psi$ and $\chi$. The modes of $\psi$ and $\chi$ are not mixed together, since operators $a_{\textbf{k}}$ and $a_{\textbf{k}}^{\dagger}$ ($b_{\textbf{k}}$ and $b_{\textbf{k}}^{\dagger}$) only act on the $|\psi>$ ($|\chi>$) part of $|s>$.